# Adding in a vector the sum of the values of a matrix in a concentric way

Tags: c

So the exercise goes like this:

We are given a matrix and we are suppose to add the elements of the matrix into a vector array in a concentric way. What I mean is that we have for example a 5x5 matrix with certain values and in another vector `sum[3]` (I assume 3 because with a 5x5 matrix we have 3 concentric "circles" of numbers) and we add them there.
I hope I was clear enough.

So anyway i remember doing something similar some weeks ago where we had to do a concentric array of numbers meaning the given the number of rows and columns the matrix should have looked like this: (I did a 3x3 here just for demonstration)

```
1 2 3
8 1 4
7 6 5
```

So basically I used the same idea here  but to no avail

I don't get the values I'm supposed to get . For those who are wondering what are the values of the matrix since I read it from a file:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
1 1 1 1 1
```

this is what I have done so  far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

int main()
{
    int v[N][N];
    int i, j;
    int k = 0;
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("file", "r");
    int sum[3] = {0,0,0};

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &v[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", v[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    while (k < 3)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
                sum[k] = sum[k] + v[i][j];
    
            for (j = i - 1; j < N - 1 - i; j++)
                sum[k] = sum[k] + v[j][N - 1 - i];
    
            for (j = N - 2 - i; j >= i; j--)
            {
                sum[k] = sum[k] + v[N - 1 - i][j];
            }

            for (j = N - 2 - i; j > i; j--)
            {
                sum[k] = sum[k] + v[j][i];
            }
    
            k++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", sum[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if I understand your question correctly....

is this what you looking for?

```
int main(void) {
  int MatrixSize = 5;

  int Matrix[5][5] = {
    {1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,3,2,2,1},
    {1,2,3,2,1},
    {1,2,2,4,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1}
  };

  int Sum[3] = {0,0,0};

  int ArraySize = 3;

  for (int k = 0; k < ArraySize; ++k) {
    for (int j = k; j < MatrixSize - k; ++j) {
      Sum[k] += Matrix[k][j];

      if (MatrixSize - 1 - k > k) {
        Sum[k] += Matrix[MatrixSize - 1 - k][j];
      }
    }

    for (int i = k + 1; i < MatrixSize-k-1; ++i) {
      Sum[k] += Matrix[i][k];
      Sum[k] += Matrix[i][MatrixSize - 1 - k];
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", Sum[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats basically it. you add into the first slot of the sum vector the sum of the elements of the first  "circle" around the matrix, then into the 2nd you add the element of the 2nd "circle" and so on. Im sorry if the question was unclear and thank you for the answer